Information loss from downsampling a signal
Given a system and an input signal $x[n]$. I want to verify whether the output $x_r[n]=x[n]$ for various forms of $x[n]$. The system first, decreases the sampling rate by $3$, to get $x_d[n]$, then increases the sampling rate by $3$ to get $x_e[n]$ and finally applies a low pass filer with cut-off frequency $\omega=\pi/3$ (figure below).

Now, for the downsampled ouput, we know the relation between Fourier transforms of $x[n]$ and $x_d[n]$:
$$X_d(e^{\iota\omega})=\frac{1}{3}[X(e^{\iota\frac{\omega}{3}})+X(e^{\iota\frac{\omega-2\pi}{3}})+X(e^{\iota\frac{\omega-4\pi}{3}})] \tag 1$$
We lose information about the original signal if there are overlaps in $X(e^{\iota\frac{\omega}{3}}),X(e^{\iota\frac{\omega-2\pi}{3}}),X(e^{\iota\frac{\omega-4\pi}{3}})$ as that would result in aliasing and it would affect the final output $x_r[n]$.
Questions.

Is this logic correct?
Downsampling is followed by upsampling, how do I check how that affects the signal, or how do I justify that it wouldn't?



Is this logic correct?

Yes.

Downsampling is followed by upsampling, how do I check how that affects the signal, or how do I justify that it wouldn't?

Check for overlaps using the math you've developed.
If there's no overlap in the three frequency regions in your (1), then there's no information lost.
I can think of cases where you could construct a system where there's overlap in the frequency domain that does not resolve to lost information, but it's weird, involving the signals from the two regions being at known phases and 90 degrees separation.  For practical signals, if there's overlap there's information loss.
